# Samba - two users with different permissions same folder

Tags: raspbian, samba, share

I have HDD connected to Raspberry, mounted to /media/pi/shared.

Also i have configured Samba share:

```
[raspShare]
comment = Pi shared folder
path = /media/pi/shared
ready only = no
browseable = yes
only guest = no
public = no
```

I have two accounts - "pi" and "userRO". Both are configured in raspberry. When I connect to RaspShare from Windows with "pi" account, everything works perfect. I can access, read, write and so on.
When I try to connect with userRO account, it gives me Access denined error. (Later I want to use this account for read only access). I'm not sure how to set up (folder?) permissions for other than pi account. Can you help me, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your Linux permissions so that `userRO` has access to the share?

Recall that Samba permissions *cannot override* Linux permissions. Therefore, if you want `userRO` to access the share through the Samba server, then `userRO` must also have the appropriate permissions in your Linux file system.